# Quando (e come) nacque l’espressione “garantito al limone”?

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Tutte (o quasi, vedi quella citata nella [risposta di @abarisone](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9790/3649)) le fonti d’informazione che sono riuscito a trovare spiegano che l’espressione “garantito al limone” trarrebbe origine da uno sketch pubblicitario di un detersivo per piatti (Last al limone), che terminava appunto con queste parole.  Questa pubblicità sarebbe stata diffusa (in Italia, ovviamente) via radio e TV non prima della seconda metà degli anni Cinquanta del secolo scorso, il che implicherebbe, chiaramente, l’impossibilità che tale modo di dire venisse usato in precedenza.

Un certo fatto mi spinge a chiedermi se questa ricostruzione non possa essere inesatta, e in particolare se sia possibile che l’espressione fosse già usata negli anni immediatamente precedenti la Seconda Guerra Mondiale.  In particolare, vorrei chiedere:

1. È possibile che l‘origine dell’espressione fosse in realtà un’altra,
   precedente, e che lo slogan pubblicitario l’abbia semplicemente
   ripresa, giocando su un modo di dire già in uso?
2. Oppure, è possibile che la pubblicità di quel detersivo al limone
   venisse già diffusa, naturalmente solo via radio, già prima
   dell’ultima guerra mondiale?

---

## Aggiunta: motivazione

[Un commento](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9788/quando-e-come-nacque-l-espressione-garantito-al-limone#comment21757_9788) suggerisce che dovrei forse spiegare cosa mi ha spinto a formulare questa domanda, e in particolare a ipotizzare che l’espressione “garantito al limone” potesse essere in uso già da prima degli anni ‘50 del Novecento.

Il dubbio mi nacque non ricordo bene quanti anni fa, leggendo il romanzo *Il giardino dei Finzi-Contini* di Giorgio Bassani, e mi è tornato in mente lo scorso giugno, perché, come ricorderete, proprio su questo libro era incentrata una delle tracce della prova scritta di italiano dell’esame di maturità (in Italia).
Chi conosce l’opera ricorderà che l’evento il quale mette, per così dire, in moto la vicenda che vi viene narrata è l’espulsione dal circolo tennistico “Eleonora d’Este” di tutti i soci “di razza ebraica”, compresi, naturalmente, i due rampolli dei Finzi-Contini, Alberto e Micòl.  Questo evento, a sua volta, è preceduto, e in realtà causato, da un altro episodio, e cioè l’interruzione della finale del doppio misto che Adriana Trentini e Bruno Lattes — ebreo, quest’ultimo — stanno inopinatamente disputando, e ancor più inopinatamente vincendo, contro Désirée Baggioli e Claudio Montemezzo; sul quattro a due per la  coppia Trentini-Lattes nel secondo set, essendo il primo già stato vinto da loro, il marchese Barbicinti, giudice-arbitro del torneo, sospende appunto la partita, adducendo come motivo (o pretesto?) la sopraggiungente oscurità; è proprio a seguito di questa interruzione che, ripeto, il circolo espellerà i soci ebrei, con la raccomandata-espresso di “accettazione delle dimissioni” inviata a Bruno Lattes addirittura *overnight*, così da impedirgli, già a partire dal giorno dopo, di ripresentarsi sul campo per riprendere l’incontro.

Bassani fa narrare l’episodio alla stessa Adriana, e fa aggiungere a Bruno alcuni commenti: secondo la sua interpretazione, il vero colpevole dell’odioso comportamento del marchese Barbicinti era stato il giovane universitario fascista Cariani, “petto da tisico e ossa da cardellino”, servile coi gerarchi suoi superiori, ma prepotente con chiunque la sua posizione di membro dei G.U.F. gli permettesse di esserlo, specie se con ciò poteva farsi bello agli occhi dei primi.  Citando direttamente dal romanzo:

> Il marchese Barbicinti era la persona che era:
> un signore distinto, senza dubbio, ma piuttosto a terra in fatto
> d’“autonomia di carburante”, e tutt’altro che un eroe. […]
> Doveva dunque essere stato uno scherzo, per Cariani,
> riempire il povero Enne Acca di tremarella.
> Gli aveva detto, magari: “E domani? Ha pensato a domani sera,
> marchese, quando il federale verrà qui, per la festa da ballo,
> e si troverà a dover premiare un… Lattes con tanto di coppa
> d’argento e relativo saluto romano?  Io, per me,
> prevedo un grosso scandalo.  E grane, grane a non finire.
> Al posto suo, dato anche che comincia a far buio,
> non ci penserei due volte a interrompere la partita”.
> Non c’era voluto niente di più, **“garantito al limone”**,
> per indurre l’altro alla grottesca e penosa irruzione
> nella quale si era prodotto.

Eccola qui: si badi bene che Bassani mette l’espressione tra virgolette, dunque direttamente in bocca a Bruno (concordemente con l’uso costante che egli fa della sua tipica tecnica stilistica di far parlare i suoi personaggi attraverso la forma del discorso indiretto, ma inserendovi le interiezioni proprie del discorso diretto); in altre parole, ne fa scientemente una frase pronunciata nel 1938.  Ecco cosa mi ha spinto a chiedermi se essa potesse essere in uso già prima della guerra.

Naturalmente, si potrebbe rispondere che la cosa è facilissimamente spiegabile come un semplice errore dell’autore; ma lo ritengo assai poco probabile.  Il romanzo è del 1962: se davvero l’idioma “garantito al limone” si diffuse nella seconda metà degli anni ‘50, quando Bassani scriveva esso doveva ancora suonare di un nuovo squillante.  Impossibile metterlo *inavvertitamente* in bocca a un personaggio di venticinque anni prima, anche perché, lungo il ciclo di pubblicazione di un’opera del genere, esiste (o, almeno, allora esisteva…) chi si prenderebbe cura di segnalare la svista.  Sarebbe come se, scrivendo ora un romanzo ambientato, diciamo, nel 1995, l’autore facesse dire a un suo personaggio, che so, “Enrico, stai sereno!”: potrebbe mai sfuggirgli il fatto che quella frase, allora, non poteva avere alcun significato?  Piuttosto, penserei, semmai, a un anacronismo *volontario*, uno dei numerosissimi indovinelli per il lettore piccoli, medi e minuscoli (come i giochi con la topografia di Ferrara, il liceo Guarini, lo stesso circolo tennistico *Eleonora d’Este*, lo stesso nome di Désirée Baggioli…), di cui, si può dire, il romanzo è costellato.

Comment: C'è qualche motivo che ti fa pensare che questa locuzione sia precedente agli anni '50?

Comment: Tenendo conto della cura con cui Bassani scriveva i suoi libri, anche a me sembra poco probabile che si tratti di un errore.

Comment: @Charo: Già, e poi esistono i correttori di bozze.  Ho aggiunto, nella domanda, un inciso a riguardo.

Comment: Potrebbe trattarsi di un'espressione di origine bolognese? Vedere "garantè a limòn" [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=vGrgAAAAMAAJ&q=%22garantito+al+limone%22&dq=%22garantito+al+limone%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_4M-LnvTcAhUDGewKHThyDSs4ChDoAQgVMAI).

Comment: Infatti l'espressione "garantè a limòn" appare nel libro [*Èl sgner Pirein*](https://www.liberliber.it/online/autori/autori-f/antonio-fiacchi/el-sgner-pirein/) di Antonio Fiacchi, pubblicato a Bologna nel 1920.

Comment: «Mo ch'is metten bèin in mèint che in sta cà que in i veinen gnanch s'i zighen... fenna che a j è viva la Giolia, che a sòn po me, lòur que in i batten barbein... **garantè a limòn**... anch che i vegnen con quî dèl numrein... a sòn bona ed fari ruzzlar tùtt zò dal scal!...»

Comment: Grazie mille, GuM, adesso la domanda è molto più compiuta e interessante. Una considerazione: siamo sicuri che le virgolette indichino che l'espressione è attribuita a uno dei personaggi e non indichino invece un'espressione lievemente impropria (nel senso di “come si suol dire, garantito al limone”)? Infine una pignoleria: i correttori di bozze non c'entrano con interventi di questo tipo. Semmai i redattori (o “editor”).

Comment: In questo periodo non ho tempo per approfondire o scrivere una risposta, ma indagherei su [questo](https://books.google.it/books?id=F6lOfYgG8NcC&q=%22garantito+al+limone%22&dq=%22garantito+al+limone%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbtMWg7fHcAhWQ2KQKHbsbCxY4FBDoAQhWMAc) (screenshot [qui](https://www.dropbox.com/s/woj65ui215b4m2l/Screen%20Shot%202018-08-17%20at%2023.02.13.png?dl=0)).

Comment: Esiste anche un libro umoristico intitolato [Garantito al limone](https://www.google.it/search?q=garantito+al+limone+marcello+d%27orta&rlz=1CDGOYI_enIT730IT730&oq=gara&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l3j69i59.1859j0j7&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) di Marcello D’Orta. Magari ci potrebbero essere riferimenti alla scelta del titolo.

Comment: @DaG:  Sembra che si tratti del racconto di una gita da Genova al Monte Rosa nel 1928: https://books.google.it/books?id=F6lOfYgG8NcC&q=gita&dq=%22garantito+al+limone%22&source=gbs_word_cloud_r&cad=5.

Comment: @Charo, per il libro di A. Fiacchi: Non so se possa avere qualche significato, ma quel libro ha una prefazione di Lorenzo Stecchetti (Olindo Guerrini), il quale è espressamente elencato, all’inizio del sesto paragrafo del terzo capitolo, fra gli autori di cui,  nella biblioteca dei Finzi-Contini, «si può dire che non mancasse nulla».  Ma siamo pur sempre nella zona di Bologna, poco dopo che vi è vissuto il Carducci…

Comment: @DaG, circa l’uso delle virgolette: qui la faccenda sta diventando una questione di critica letteraria, ma direi proprio che l’interpretazione alternativa a cui fai cenno sarebbe del tutto fuori luogo in questo caso.  Circa i correttori di bozze: ho modificato la domanda, “correggendo i correttori” (ecco, *qui* sto usando le virgolette nel senso che dici tu! :-)  Grazie per la segnalazione dell’errore!

Answer (score 2):

Una [risposta della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/una-risposta-garantita-al-limone/2918) a vari lettori che ponevano domande o commenti analoghi a questo sembra abbastanza definitiva. Riassumendo:

- Il riferimento a *Carosello* è frequente, ma nessuno sa dire a quale si riferirebbe nello specifico, né riesce a mostrare un filmato.
- Al di là al passo di Bassani (ambientato nel 1938 ma scritto successivamente), esistono anche testi effettivamente della fine degli anni '20 e dei primi anni '30 in cui compare questa espressione; per esempio, “il divertimento è garantito al limone! Speriamo solo che il tempo ci permetta di raggiungere la cima” (Annuario e strenna dell’Istituto Vittorino da Feltre (anno scolastico 1927-28), Genova, tipografia Derelitti, 1928, n. 6, p. 131), e un articolo in cui “garantito al limone” compare addirittura già all'interno di un elenco di frasi fatte. Quindi la pubblicità del detersivo, se anche esiste, avrebbe ripreso un modo di dire precedente.
- La locuzione inglese *no lemon guarantee*, a parte il senso diverso, non sembra attestata in Google Books prima degli anni '70.

Rinvio ovviamente alla risposta della Crusca per le argomentazioni complete.

Comment: Qualche informazione affidabile, finalmente! Grazie, @DaG!

Comment: È curioso vedere che la prima apparizione che sono riusciti a trovare sia la stessa che avevi individuato tu anni fa.

Comment: È vero, @Charo! Sono contento della conferma, e anche dell'articolo del 1933.

Answer (score 1):

In questo [portale informativo di Castellammare di Stabia: Storia, Cultura, Natura e Tradizioni Stabiesi](https://www.liberoricercatore.it/modi-di-dire/) viene riportata un’ulteriore ipotesi sull’origine dell’espressione:

> Garantito a limone! molti asseriscono che le origini di questo famoso
>   modo di dire, con il quale si promettere al proprio interlocutore la
>   sicurezza al 100% di un’affermazione. debbano attribuirsi alla
>   pubblicità di un vecchio carosello televisivo dedicato al detersivo
>   “Last”, il cui slogan recitava: “Pulito e splendente, garantito al
>   limone!”.  Affascinante ed interessante invece la traccia di ricerca
>   suggerita da Ferdinando Fontanella, con la quale si retrocederebbe la
>   data di origine di questo caratteristico modo di dire, **attribuendolo
>   addirittura agli acquafrescai (acquaioli) di Castellammare di Stabia (città delle
>   Acque per antonomasia), che volendo garantire la bontà delle acque
>   somministrate ai clienti, strofinavano mezzi limoni sull’orlo delle
>   brocche e poi risciacquando abbondantemente garantivano l’assoluta
>   igienicità, da ciò: “Garantito a limone!”**.

Comment: Sì, conoscevo già quel sito e la spiegazione che riporti, ma sinceramente non l’avevo ritenuta molto affidabile… :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ricordo di avere sentito l'espressione "Garantito al limone" in un film di guerra americano, la 2ª guerra mondiale, perciò Carosello sembrerebbe fuori discussione. La pronunciava un sergente trafficone-imbroglione che aveva sempre in bocca un sigaro.
Però questa espressione potrebbe essere la traduzione italiana di un equivalente detto americano.

Comment: In effetti, si trovano riferimenti a “no lemon guarantee” che sembrano riferirsi all'appellativo “lemon” dato ad automobili difettose fin dall'inizio. Quindi “no lemon guarantee” è la garanzia data dal venditore che l'auto non è difettosa. La traduzione “garantito al limone” è pessima, ma la derivazione sembra plausibile.

Comment: Ricordi che film era? Questa risposta ci dice qualcosa sul doppiaggio italiano e quindi sarebbe interessante sapere di quando è il film e quando è stato distribuito in Italia. (A volte film angloamericani sono arrivati in Italia, per ovvi motivi, vari anni dopo la loro prima uscita.)

Answer (score 0):

Negli anni 60 il prof di elettrotecnica all'ITIS Fermi di Roma usava frequentemente quest'espressione. Mi pare ci dicesse che era riferita a delle caramelle o altri dolciumi in voga prima della guerra, di certo non parlò mai di detersivi.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie dell'intervento. Per questo tipo di domande, però, di solito si aspetta una risposta basata su qualche fonte affidabile.

Comment: Be’, comunque grazie per la notizia. +1!

Answer (score -1):

Deriva da un vecchio spot televisivo del Carosello. L’oggetto dello spot è il detersivo per piatti al limone Last, il cui slogan recitava: “Pulito e splendente, garantito al limone” a sottolineare la caratteristica principale del prodotto che era il profumo al limone.

Comment: Benvenuto! Credo che l'OP abbia già sottolineato abbondantemente questo punto. Per caso hai qualche altra informazione riguardo ai punti piú specifici nella domanda originale?

Comment: @user5123: Credo che dovresti cancellare questa risposta, in quanto evidentemente data senza aver letto per intero la domanda… ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Io sono toscana,ormai romana. In casa questo modo di dire, si usava già, negli anni '40 quando io ero bimbetta.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE! Suggeriamo di provare a leggere le pagine [tour] e [help] e di dare un'occhiata alle altre domande e risposte per capire come il sito funziona. Non è un forum, ma un sito di domande e risposte. Perciò, per favore, fai del tuo meglio per rispondere davvero alla domanda. Non esitare a chiedere aiuto se ne hai bisogno.